# jquery method showing error

Tags: jquery

I've this in a page

```
       $(".dsd").click(function(){
```

When i used firebug,it gives me this error

```
     $(".dsd").click is not a function
```

What is this?

Comment: Are you sure you have a element with the class 'dsd'? Post the whole `click` function.

Comment: post more code and make sure jquery is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be due to a conflict with some other client framework you might be using which has hijacked the `$` function. Take a look at [`jQuery.noConlict`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for possible solutions about how you could use jQuery with other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Its seems to be a conflict in my point of view. You have a libary that also want the shortcode $. Have a look at *jQuery.noConflict* and try to use *jQuery(".dsd").click...*

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".dsd").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () { ... });
});
```